# How to get Moxy/JAXB unmarshal to accept prefix in XML document [Reposition as Getting JAXB to accept missing namespace xmlns in root node element]

Tags: jaxb, moxy

I am trying to unmarshal a XML document from a web service but is unable to setup JAXB/Moxy to read the namespace prefix "ae".

I can get it partially working by manually stripping the prefix from the XML document. I have also tried using the package-info.java approach.

Please help point where I am going wrong?

**Sample of the XML document**

```
    <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:c14n="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#" xmlns:wsc="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-secureconversation/200512" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:diag="urn:SerenaDiagnostics" xmlns:ae="urn:sbmappservices72">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header>
    </SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ae:GetItemsByQueryResponse>
    <ae:return>
<ae:item>
<ae:id>
<ae:displayName>
</ae:displayName>
<ae:id>15</ae:id>
<ae:uuid>36df5681-652b-4fb9-b7e4-b14935c6920b</ae:uuid>
<ae:tableId>1064</ae:tableId>
<ae:tableIdItemId>1064:15</ae:tableIdItemId>
<ae:issueId>
</ae:issueId>
</ae:id>
<ae:title>CONFIGURATION</ae:title>
<ae:url>http://scsmwdcuapp01:80/tmtrack/tmtrack.dll?IssuePage&amp;RecordId=15&amp;Template=view&amp;TableId=1064</ae:url>
<ae:extendedField>
<ae:id>
<ae:displayName>Related Category</ae:displayName>
<ae:id>827</ae:id>
<ae:uuid>043aa994-e155-449c-bf8c-2397e5d4c975</ae:uuid>
<ae:dbName>RELATED_CATEGORY</ae:dbName>
</ae:id>
<ae:value>
<ae:displayValue>MAINFRAME APPLICATION</ae:displayValue>
<ae:internalValue>1063:3</ae:internalValue>
<ae:uuid>b2814974-c370-409a-980a-d8b9af9de7b7</ae:uuid>
</ae:value>
</ae:extendedField>
<ae:extendedField>
<ae:id>
<ae:displayName>SNSys_ID</ae:displayName>
<ae:id>828</ae:id>
<ae:uuid>4baeb994-a23d-4ccf-bf93-786047c09bb9</ae:uuid>
<ae:dbName>SNSYS_ID</ae:dbName>
</ae:id>
<ae:value>
<ae:displayValue>122f66b26fe57500bd06cbe64f3ee456</ae:displayValue>
<ae:internalValue>122f66b26fe57500bd06cbe64f3ee456</ae:internalValue>
<ae:uuid>
</ae:uuid>
</ae:value>
</ae:extendedField>
<ae:subtasks>
</ae:subtasks>
</ae:item>
<ae:item>
.....
```

**The Moxy XML binding file.**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml-bindings 
        xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/oxm"
        package-name="egress"
        version="2.5"
        xml-mapping-metadata-complete="true">   
    <xml-schema element-form-default="QUALIFIED">
        <xml-ns prefix="ae" namespace-uri="urn:sbmappservices72"/>
    </xml-schema>
    <java-types>
        <java-type name="QueryResponse" xml-accessor-type="FIELD">
        <xml-root-element name="ae:GetItemsByQueryResponse"/>
            <java-attributes>
                <xml-element java-attribute="returnRecords" xml-path="return"/>
            </java-attributes>
        </java-type>
        <java-type name="AuxRecords" xml-accessor-type="FIELD">
        <xml-root-element name="return"/>
            <java-attributes>
                <xml-element java-attribute="recordsList" xml-path="item"/>
            </java-attributes>
        </java-type>
        <java-type name="AuxRecord" xml-accessor-type="FIELD">
        <xml-root-element name="result"/>
            <java-attributes>
                <xml-element java-attribute="name" xml-path="title/text()"/>
                <xml-element java-attribute="id" xml-path="id"/>
                <xml-element java-attribute="extensionList" xml-path="extendedField"/>
            </java-attributes>      
        </java-type>
        <java-type name="AuxRecordId" xml-accessor-type="FIELD">
        <xml-root-element name="id"/>
            <java-attributes>
                <xml-element java-attribute="itemId" xml-path="id/text()"/>
                <xml-element java-attribute="tableId" xml-path="tableId/text()"/>
            </java-attributes>      
        </java-type>
        <java-type name="ExtendedField" xml-accessor-type="FIELD">
        <xml-root-element name="extendedField"/>
            <java-attributes>
                <xml-element java-attribute="id" xml-path="id"/>
                <xml-element java-attribute="value" xml-path="value"/>
            </java-attributes>      
        </java-type>
        <java-type name="FieldId" xml-accessor-type="FIELD">
        <xml-root-element name="id"/>
            <java-attributes>
                <xml-element java-attribute="displayName" xml-path="displayName/text()"/>
            </java-attributes>      
        </java-type>
        <java-type name="FieldValue" xml-accessor-type="FIELD">
        <xml-root-element name="value"/>
            <java-attributes>
                <xml-element java-attribute="displayValue" xml-path="displayValue/text()"/>
            </java-attributes>      
        </java-type>
    </java-types>
</xml-bindings>
```

**Partial listing of Java Classes**

```
@XmlRootElement(name="ae:GetItemsByQueryResponse")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class QueryResponse {
    
    @XmlElement (name="return")
    AuxRecords returnRecords = null;

    public AuxRecords getReturnRecords() {
        return returnRecords;
    }

    public void setReturnRecords(AuxRecords records) {
        this.returnRecords = records;
    }
}

@XmlRootElement(name="return")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class AuxRecords {

    @XmlElement(name="item")
    private List<AuxRecord> recordsList = null;

    public List<AuxRecord> getRecords() {
        return recordsList;
    }
    
    public void setRecords(List<AuxRecord> inputRecordsList) {
        this.recordsList = inputRecordsList;
    }   
}

@XmlRootElement(name="item")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class AuxRecord {

    // snow=u_category, sbm=ae:title
    @XmlElement (name="title")
    String name = null;
    
    // sbm=ae:id
    @XmlElement (name="id")
    AuxRecordId id = null;

    @XmlElement(name="extendedField")
    private List<ExtendedField> extensionList = null;
    
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    
    public AuxRecordId getId() {
        return id;
    }
    
    public void setId(AuxRecordId inputId) {
        this.id = inputId;
    }

    public List<ExtendedField> getExtensionList() {
        return extensionList;
    }

    public void setExtensionList(List<ExtendedField> extensionList) {
        this.extensionList = extensionList;
    }

    public Object getExtensionSnSysId() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}

@XmlRootElement(name="extendedField")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class ExtendedField {
    
    @XmlElement (name="id")
    FieldId id;
    
    @XmlElement (name="value")
    FieldValue value;
    
    public FieldId getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(FieldId id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public FieldValue getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    public void setValue(FieldValue value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

**My codes to unmarshal the XML document in POJO classes.**

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException{
        
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.OXM_METADATA_SOURCE, "xml-bindings.xml");
        JAXBContext context1 = JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class[] {QueryResponse.class}, properties);
        
        Marshaller marshal1 = context1.createMarshaller();
        Unmarshaller umarshal1 = context1.createUnmarshaller();
//      umarshal1.setEventHandler(new javax.xml.bind.helpers.DefaultValidationEventHandler());      
        QueryResponse qresp = (QueryResponse) umarshal1.unmarshal(new File("c:\\temp\\ae_egress.xml"));
        
        marshal1.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshal1.marshal(qresp, System.out);

    }
}
```

**Exceptions**

```
Exception Description: An error occurred unmarshalling the document
Internal Exception: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/c:/temp/ae_egress.xml; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 35; The prefix "ae" for element "ae:GetItemsByQueryResponse" is not bound.]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBUnmarshaller.handleXMLMarshalException(JAXBUnmarshaller.java:980)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBUnmarshaller.unmarshal(JAXBUnmarshaller.java:126)
    at com.citi.sbm.egress.Test.main(Test.java:27)
```

***UPDATE***

Changing the input source XML document root element node to

```
<ae:GetItemsByQueryResponse xmlns:ae="urn:sbmappservices72">
<ae:return>
.....
```

clear the exception.  Since it is suppose to be a SOAP response, I cannot be modifying it as in my test ae_egress.xml.  Beside modifying the DOM document or the InputStream or XmlInputStream on the fly before passing it to the unmarshal, is there some switch or option in JAXB or MOXy that will also solve the problem?

Here's the package-info.java file that reside in the test package.

```
@XmlSchema (  namespace="urn:sbm,appservices72", 
elementFormDefault=XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED,
xmlns={
@XmlNs(prefix="ae", namespaceURI="urn:sbmappservices72")}
)
package egress;
import javax.xml./bind.annotation.*;
```

Comment: Base on Batman_2009 assistance, I have modified the ae-egress.xml to <ae:GetItemsQueryResponse> xmlns:ae="urn:sbmappservices72".  That immediately clear the exception and the XML elements are parsed as objects.  I need to re-position the problem.  Since the SOAP envelope containing the namespace declaration is not presented to JAXB and the root element does not contain the namespace declaration, how can I get JAXB to ignore that so that it would not trigger the input mismatch?

Answer (score 1):

I did not re-create the exact issue but I have created a sample with namespaces during the `Unmarshalling`. I am not entirely sure if it would help but see if it helps:

Following is my `XML` that I would like to `Unmarshal`:

```
<Customer xmlns:ae="urn:sbmappservices72">
    <extension>
        <ae:name>Batman</ae:name>
        <ae:age>25</ae:age>
    </extension>
</Customer>
```

Following is my `Customer` class:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Customer")
@XmlType(name = "Customer", propOrder = {"extension"})
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
public class AnotherCustomer {

    private Extension extension;
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
@XmlType(name = "Extension", propOrder = {"name", "age"})
class Extension {
    @XmlElement(namespace = "urn:sbmappservices72", name = "name")
    private String name;
    @XmlElement(namespace = "urn:sbmappservices72", name = "age")
    private String age;
}
```

Following is the `unmarshalling` main class:

```
public class AnotherUnmarshalling {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws XMLStreamException, JAXBException {
        final InputStream inputStream = Unmarshalling.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("customer.xml");
        final XMLStreamReader xmlStreamReader = XMLInputFactory.newInstance().createXMLStreamReader(inputStream);
        final Unmarshaller unmarshaller = JAXBContext.newInstance(AnotherCustomer.class).createUnmarshaller();
        final AnotherCustomer customer = unmarshaller.unmarshal(xmlStreamReader, AnotherCustomer.class).getValue();
        System.out.println(customer.toString());
    }
}
```

Not sure if you have already looked into this but please look into following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15773023/7584240

Comment: Thanks you for taking the time to look into the problem and coming up with a answer.  I've looked through your solution and identified the points of differences.  1. XmlElement has the namespace decorator, 2 the signature for unmarshal uses xmlStreamReader instead of inputStream.  I have tried adding the namespace decorator to all the classes XmlElement and ran a re-test.  The exception is still there.  I am not sure if changing the use of the unmarshal function to use XmlStreamReader should make a difference to the internal operation of the function.

Comment: My suspicion is that the JAXB parser is getting hang up on the first node <ae:GetItemsByQueryResponse>, which I notice that does not have the xmlns="urn:sbmappservices72" declaration.  That is in the SOAP envelope which is strip away since I am passing to the unmarshal the DOM document.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved.  Not sure why the initial code does not generate the xmlns into the Document from the SoapBody.  New runs of the codes after extracting the content as Document has the perquisite xmlns.